# error generated by flutter while deploying an app

Tags: gradle, flutter, dart

i am learning flutter and this is the error i get in both vs code as well as android studio.

i tried looking for answer and also tried some fixes but never worked

flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on Redmi Note 7 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.6s
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "E:\flutterprojects\testerapp\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
>   Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\pragya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
>   License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 accepted.
>   Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)".

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'E:\flutterprojects\testerapp\android\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  >   Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  >   org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
  Command: E:\flutterprojects\testerapp\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

i expect the code to run. this is the default code provided by dart so there should have been no mistakes in the code.

Comment: how did you create `testerapp`? is it some existing code or brand new one?

Comment: please check the code inside E:\flutterprojects\testerapp\android\build.gradle file on line number 24

Comment: the app was created using ```flutter create testerapp```

Comment: I can surely check the code in the file but I don't know what to do while i am in there.

Comment: Could you post the output of Doctor

(run `flutter doctor` on the app directory)